# Get file contents from .NET API in Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, blob

I am working on an Angular 7 and .NET Core application. I have to pass file (file contents) from .NET API to Angular. My API code is:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetLicenseInformation()
{
    try
    {
        string fileName = "TestLicense";

        string filePath = PathOfFile;

        var bytearray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pathToSaveLicenseFile);
        const string contentType = "text/plain";
        var result = new FileContentResult(bytearray, contentType)
        {
            FileDownloadName = fileName
        };

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    
    }
    return null;
}
```

My service code on Angular side is:

```
getLicenseInformation(): Observable<any> {

return this.http.get(BaseUrl + 'getlicenseinformation',  {responseType: 'blob' , observe: 'response'});
}
```

My code of component is:

```
ngOnInit() {

this.uploadService.getLicenseInformation().subscribe(data => {
  var blob = new Blob([data.blob()], {type: 'text/plain'});
  })
}
```

When i run the code, i get the exception **data.blob is not a function**.

I have also tried **data.body()**, this does not give exception but i dont get the data of the file. I have tried this API with postman and its working fine i.e. i do get the file contents in postman. What may be the issue ?  What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this approach:https://www.blexin.com/en-US/Article/Blog/Uploading-and-Downloading-files-with-Angular-and-AspNet-Core-22